# convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{-x} + 1}{|log(x)|^n +1}$ if $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

i want to study the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{-x} + 1}{|log(x)|^n +1}$ if $x>0$

so i started by rewriting the series as:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{n^{x}} +  1}{|log(x)|^n +1}$  by getting rid of the minus at numerator

which is equivalent to :

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1 + n^x }{n^{x}}}{|log(x)|^n +1}$ = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1 + n^x }{n^x(|log(x)|^n +1)}$          (I)

which i rewrote as:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1 }{(|log(x)|^n +1)}+ \frac{1}{n^x(|log(x)|^n +1)}$ by dividing the numerator and factoring out $n^x$

now notice that both these $\frac{1 }{(|log(x)|^n +1)}$ and $\frac{1}{n^x(|log(x)|^n +1)}$ are non-negative for all $n,x>0$

and we may study their convergence separately. indeed if the series

(II) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1 }{(|log(x)|^n +1)}$

and

(III) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x(|log(x)|^n +1)}$

both converge we can deduce that also (I) has to converge. and if at least one of them for some x happens to diverge we can deduce that for such an x also (I) has to diverge.

now just notice that for all $x \ge e$ (III) converges by series p-test

now look at (II), by applying ratio test we get that it is divergent if $1/e<x<e$ and convergent for $x>e$ or $1/e>x$

for $x=e,1/e$ notice (II) diverges in both cases

now, we are just interested in the behaviour of (III) in $x<1/e$, since notice we know that (I) has to diverge for $1/e \le x \le e$ and converge for $x>e$ by the above.

---

now notice that we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n}{n^x} \to \infty$ if $a>1$
since for $x<1/e$ we have $|log(x)| > 1$ we are in this case. so (III) is equivalent to:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{|log(x)|^n} $ which is convergent for x<1/e

so to recap i get that the series is convergent $\forall x>e$ and $x<1/e$, otherwise it is divergent.

i have some doubts on the last part(under the traced line, i don't know if what i did is fully justificable) , but I may very well made other mistakes. thanks for the help

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SumConvergence%5B%28n%5E%28-1%29+%2B+1%29%2F%28Log%5B1%5D%5En+%2B+1%29%2C+n%5D)
[Wolfram Alpha 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SumConvergence%5B%28n%5E%28-2%29+%2B+1%29%2F%28Log%5B2%5D%5En+%2B+1%29%2C+n%5D)

Should have been:
`SumConvergence[(n^(-1) + 1)/(Abs[Log[1]]^n + 1), n]` and `SumConvergence[(n^(-2) + 1)/(Abs[Log[2]]^n + 1), n]`

Comment: @MatsGranvik what does it mean? is it just a way to check if the result holds?

Comment: @MatsGranvik indeed it does not for all $x>0$,you just look at the case $x=e$ for instance or the 2 you posted. what i meant in the title is just studying  the behaviour of the series by letting x>0 be free, it's about finding for which x the series converges and for which it does not.

Comment: You are probably right. `SumConvergence[(n^(-1/(Exp[1])) + 1)/(Abs[Log[1/(Exp[1])]]^n + 1), n]` gives False, while `SumConvergence[(n^(-1/(Exp[1] + 1/1000000)) + 
    1)/(Abs[Log[1/(Exp[1] + 1/1000000)]]^n + 1), n]` gives True. `1/1000000` is taken to be a small number.

Comment: @MatsGranvik thanks for your time, didn't know wolfram was so powerful, it looks very useful

Answer (score 1):

Let:
$$a_n=\frac{\frac{1}{n^{x}} +  1}{|log(x)|^n +1}\sim \left|\frac{1}{\log(x)}\right|^n$$
This is a power series that converges if:
$$\left|\frac{1}{\log(x)}\right|< 1 \implies x\in \left(0,\frac{1}{e}\right)\cap (e,+\infty)$$
Here we have used asympotic criteria and comparison test.

If $x=\frac{1}{e}$, the series do not converge because $\frac{1}{e}<1$.

If $x=e>1$ converge by the comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^k}$.

Comment: @invictus: if this answer has been useful, let me know, smashing that b+1 and accepted answer buttons.